# CSS Weird behavour with nth-of-type(even or odd)

Tags: html, css

I have some css selectors to style every even and every odd occurance but for whatever reason the odd even selection is switch for a particular set of elements which are inside a div

[image: Image showing Even odd switch]

As you can see "How Often should have a turquoise border but it doesn't, If anyone knows why this is happening it would be much appreciated if you could give me an answer

here is an example of the CSS & HTML

```css
.profile-container .input-container:nth-of-type(even){
    border: 2px solid gold;
}

.profile-container .input-container:nth-of-type(odd){
    border: 2px solid turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-title">
    <h1>Customer</h1>
    <button class="" tabindex="0" type="button">
        Delete
    </button>
</div>
<div class="profile-container">
    <div class="input-container"><label>First Name</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Last Name</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Email</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Phone</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Customer Id</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Sub Id</label></div>
    
    <div style="margin-top: 20px; border-top: 1px dashed grey; padding-top: 20px;">
        <div class="page-title" style="max-width: unset; margin-left: 0px;">
            <h1>Subscription</h1>
            <button class="" tabindex="0" type="button">
                Cancel Subscription
            </button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="input-container"><label>How Often</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>Inside Cleaning</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>intro price</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>Price</label></div>
    </div>
    
    <div style="margin-top: 20px; border-top: 1px dashed grey; padding-top: 20px;">
        <div class="input-container"><label>Address</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>Postal Code</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>City</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>Size(m<sup>2</sup>)</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>Stories</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>type</label></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: When i remove this (The Subscription page title) it actually works as expected

```html
<div class="page-title" style="max-width: unset; margin-left: 0px;">
  <h1>Subscription</h1>
  
  <button class="" tabindex="0" type="button">
    Cancel Subscription
  </button>
</div>
```

```css
.profile-container .input-container:nth-of-type(even){
    border: 2px solid gold;
}

.profile-container .input-container:nth-of-type(odd){
    border: 2px solid turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-title">
    <h1>Customer</h1>
    <button class="" tabindex="0" type="button">
        Delete
    </button>
</div>
<div class="profile-container">
    <div class="input-container"><label>First Name</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Last Name</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Email</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Phone</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Customer Id</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Sub Id</label></div>
    
    <div style="margin-top: 20px; border-top: 1px dashed grey; padding-top: 20px;">
        <div class="page-title" style="max-width: unset; margin-left: 0px;">
            <h1>Subscription</h1>
            <button class="" tabindex="0" type="button">
                Cancel Subscription
            </button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="input-container"><label>How Often</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>Inside Cleaning</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>intro price</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>Price</label></div>
    </div>
    
    <div style="margin-top: 20px; border-top: 1px dashed grey; padding-top: 20px;">
        <div class="input-container"><label>Address</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>Postal Code</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>City</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>Size(m<sup>2</sup>)</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>Stories</label></div>
        <div class="input-container"><label>type</label></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The results of the code do not match the image so it's hard to tell what you actually expect vs what you get instead. Although I think I already know the problem but I won't waste time guessing trying to explain a CSS style without proper layout in example.

Comment: @zer00ne what do you mean it doesn't match? Doesn't "How Often" have a yellow border for you. The point is it should be blue based on the selectors and code an it's not. Basically no color should be followed or preceded by the same color

Comment: Like I said already it's a waste of time to start rewriting your code to match what *I think it should look like*. It's the burden of the asker to provide accurate, minimal, and comprehensible information. You are asking a CSS question and post some HTML and only 2 CSS rulesets -- the nature of CSS is that every ruleset affects whatever is below it...so where are these 2 lines? At the bottom, the top, in a `<style>` tag? In `<link>`? If in a tag then where in the page is it located? Not sure why it matters you already accepted an answer from someone willing to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MDN :nth-of-type() reference:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) "The `:nth-of-type()` CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their position among siblings of the same type ***(tag name)***." You may be expecting it only to look for matching siblings with your selector class of `.input-container`, but in fact it is looking for siblings with the same tag, which is `<div>`, and shared among several other elements in the section, not just those with the `.input-container` class.

It works as expected when you remove the subscription title because those `div`'s are being counted in the `nth-of-type` declared as `even` and `odd` declarations in your stylesheet.

You're saying `odd` and `even` `nth-of-type` children of `.profile-container` which selects all divs of that type including `<div style="margin-top: 20px; border-top: 1px dashed grey; padding-top: 20px;">`.

I would nest all `input-container`'s in their own respective divs and use the `nth-of-type` `odd` and `even` declaration on those new parents. In this example, I called it `.more-inputs`. This way the `odd` and `even` are only targeting the divs with the class `input-container` and not other divs nested within `.profile-container`.

See below:

```css
.more-inputs .input-container:nth-of-type(even) {
  border: 2px solid gold;
}

.more-inputs .input-container:nth-of-type(odd) {
  border: 2px solid turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-title">
  <h1>Customer</h1>
  <button class="" tabindex="0" type="button">Delete</button>
</div>
<div class="profile-container">
  <div class="more-inputs">
    <div class="input-container"><label>First Name</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Last Name</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Email</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Phone</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Customer Id</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Sub Id</label></div>
  </div>
  <div class="page-title" style="max-width: unset; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 20px; border-top: 1px dashed grey; padding-top: 20px;">
    <h1>Subscription</h1>
    <button class="" tabindex="0" type="button">Cancel Subscription</button>
  </div>
  <div class="more-inputs">
    <div class="input-container"><label>How Often</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Inside Cleaning</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>intro price</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Price</label></div>
  </div>

  <div style="margin-top: 20px; border-top: 1px dashed grey; padding-top: 20px;" class="more-inputs">
    <div class="input-container"><label>Address</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Postal Code</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>City</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Size(m<sup>2</sup>)</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>Stories</label></div>
    <div class="input-container"><label>type</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
```